# jquery slider navigation

Tags: jquery, animation, slider

I am creating a web page that uses a horizontal slider and animations to scrollTo hidden divs.  When I click home I would like it to go to the first slide-panel div no matter what slide panel or mainContent div  it is on. I've been messing around with the scrollTo that simply scrolls up to the slide panel but i cant figure out how to make it go back to the first panel. 
Any ideas?

```
$(function() {  
  $('#contact').click(function() {      
   $('#contactDiv').show();
   $.scrollTo( '#contactDiv', 800, {easing:'swing', offset:{top:-130}} );
   if (currPanel != 1)      
   /*???? idk what to do here but i want it to scroll and slide to the first slide-panel                          
 });
});
```

please see the jsFiddle for complete code:
http://jsfiddle.net/mU9Nu/

Comment: i created a plugin long time ago... check it out on http://freelee.ch/downloads/default.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a good solution for you:

```
$('#home').click(function() {
    $('.slide-panel').removeClass('active');
    $( $('.slide-panel')[0] ).addClass('active');
});
```

The `$( $('.classname')[i] )` is referring to `.classname`'s like an array.

Comment: i couldnt get that to work. $.scrollTo('#full-slider').children('.slide-panel')[0] this selects the right div but how to I scroll/slide/animate to it? im trying  $(function() {    
 $('#home').click(function() {
  
  $.scrollTo('.slide-panel', 800, {easing:'swing', offset:{top:-130}} );    
  $('#full-slider').children('.slide-panel')[0].animate({
  left: "400px"
  },1000)
  });
});